# How to get the elapsed time of Microsoft TTS speech?

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I now use following function to realize a TTS service.

```
int tts(LPCWSTR text){
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);         
    CLSID CLSID_SpVoice;
    CLSIDFromProgID(_T("SAPI.SpVoice"), &CLSID_SpVoice);
    ISpVoice *pSpVoice = NULL;
    IEnumSpObjectTokens *pSpEnumTokens = NULL;

    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ISpVoice, (void**)&pSpVoice))){
        return -1;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(SpEnumTokens(SPCAT_VOICES, NULL, NULL, &pSpEnumTokens))){
        ISpObjectToken *pSpToken = NULL;
        SpFindBestToken(SPCAT_VOICES, L"Gender=Male", L"Name=Microsoft Simplified Chinese", &pSpToken);
        pSpVoice->SetVoice(pSpToken);
        pSpVoice->Speak(text, SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);
        pSpEnumTokens->Release();        
    }

    pSpVoice->Release();
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible for me to get the elapsed time of each character being spoken? Or is it constant (if the speech rate is set)? The purpose is that I want to show some facial animations to match the speech...

Comment: Seems not practical as the library is closed. Currently I assume the speech is of even speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the elapsed time; you could use Viseme events to trigger your animations.

Since you're using C++, use [ISpVoice::SetInterest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717856(v=vs.85).aspx) to describe the set of events that you want, and one of the [ISpNotifySource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717961(v=vs.85).aspx) methods (depending on what your outer code is doing) to get events delivered to you.

Microsoft has a detailed [workthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) available in case this sketch isn't helpful.

Note that the exact *set* of visemes (and what visemes map to which values) are language dependent.   For US English, the visemes are defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431873(v=vs.85).aspx).  For Chinese, the mapping from phoneme to viseme isn't publically defined.

On the other hand, you can use the viseme events as *triggers*, and not really care about the actual viseme *values*.

Assuming you have a message loop somewhere in your app, your code would look like this:

```
CLSID CLSID_SpVoice;
CLSIDFromProgID(_T("SAPI.SpVoice"), &CLSID_SpVoice);
ISpVoice *pSpVoice = NULL;
IEnumSpObjectTokens *pSpEnumTokens = NULL;
ULONGLONG  ullMyEvents = SPFEI(SPEI_VISEME);

if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ISpVoice, (void**)&pSpVoice))){
    return -1;
}

if (SUCCEEDED(SpEnumTokens(SPCAT_VOICES, NULL, NULL, &pSpEnumTokens))){
    ISpObjectToken *pSpToken = NULL;
    SpFindBestToken(SPCAT_VOICES, L"Gender=Male", L"Name=Microsoft Simplified Chinese", &pSpToken);
    pSpVoice->SetVoice(pSpToken);
    // Set type of events the client is interested in.
    pSpVoice->SetInterest(ullMyEvents, ullMyEvents);
    // deliver a WM_APP message when a SAPI event arrives.   
    // Use a different message ID for real code.
    pSpVoice->SetNotifyWindowMessage(hWnd, WM_APP, 0, 0);
    pSpVoice->Speak(text, SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);
    pSpEnumTokens->Release();        
}

pSpVoice->Release();
```

Later, in your message loop, you need to handle the SAPI message:

```
  case WM_APP:
     SPEVENT eventItem;
     memset( &eventItem;, 0,sizeof(SPEVENT));
     while( pVoice->GetEvents(1, &eventItem;, NULL ) == S_OK )
     {
       switch(eventItem.eEventId )
       {
          case SPEI_VISEME:
             .
             .
             .
             break;

          default:
             break;
       }

     SpClearEvent( eventItem );
```